# Is there a url you can enter in your browser to log out of WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know if there is a way to enter a logout command for WordPress in the url?

Similar to cache clearing methods like entering "yoursite.com/?shopping=reset" to clear the cache of some ecommerce plugins.

My current project requires me to hide the wordpress backend for subscribers...somewhat annoying to comment the filter to disable wp-admin when I need to switch accounts.

Comment: How did you disable wp-admin?

Comment: **
 * Disable admin bar on the frontend of your website
 * for subscribers.
 */
function themeblvd_disable_admin_bar() { 
    if( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') )
        add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); 
}

/**
 * Redirect back to homepage and not allow access to 
 * WP admin for Subscribers.
 */
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        wp_redirect( site_url() );
        exit;       
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themeblvd_disable_admin_bar' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these

```
<li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('$index.php'); ?>">Logg ut</a></li>
```

Or

```
<a href="http://codebreach.in/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http://codebreach.in/">LogOut</a>
```

Not sure if the second one still works.